# Deselect default selected cell on selecting any other cell in UICollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, calendar, uicollectionviewcell

Using UICollectionView to display calendar, I have made today's date selected by default and want to deselect that when any other date selected. Below is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalenderCell", for: indexPath) as! CalenderCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.lblDayName.text = arrCalendarDays[indexPath.item]
    cell.lblDate.text = arrCalendarOnlyDate[indexPath.item]
    
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        if !isTodayDate {
        cell.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    isTodayDate = true

// Tried below code but not working
   /* collectionViewWeekCalendar.indexPathsForSelectedItems?
        .forEach {
            self.collectionViewWeekCalendar.deselectItem(at: $0, animated: false) }
    */
    let selectedCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionViewWeekCalendar.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.isSelected = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionViewWeekCalendar.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!
    selectedCell.isSelected = false
}
```

[image]

Problem is that, when selecting any other date, today's selected date is not getting deselect. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

the hacky and easiest way (i  think)
use  selected  index

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalenderCell", for: indexPath) as! CalenderCollectionViewCell

  cell.lblDayName.text = arrCalendarDays[indexPath.item]
  cell.lblDate.text = arrCalendarOnlyDate[indexPath.item]

  if sellectedIndex == indexPath {
    cell.isSelected = true
  } else {
    cell.isSelected = false
  }

  return cell 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndex = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

and  at  the start,

```
set selectedIndex = today date Index
```